# How to type-hint/inject two different class in the post method controller laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BuyerController
{
   public function saveBuyer(Request $request,ServerRequestInterface $request )
   {
        //this is POST request controller (trying to inject 2 classes , is this possible?)
   }
}
```

Is it possible or a way to inject two different classes which are Request and ServerRequestInterface for post method controller laravel ?

Comment: AFAIK the typehint classes needs to be injected via the construct() method only.

Comment: @AlbertRaj what is AFAIK ?

Comment: "As far as I know."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class BuyerController
{
     protected $serverRequest; // this attribute will use for injected by ServerRequestInterface Class

     public function __construct(ServerRequestInterface $serverRequest)
     {
         $this->serverRequest = $serverRequest; //injecting ServerRequestInterface to this attribute 
     }

     public function saveBuyer(Request $request)
     {
        // $this->serverRequest (injected by ServerRequestInterface Class) 
        // $request (injected by Request Class)
        // now can use $this->serverRequest (for ServerRequestInterface Class) and $request (for Request Class)
        dd($this->serverRequest,$request);
     }
}
```

You can inject only in Request class and modal classes in functions. there  is an other way arround you can inject the classes and interfaces in controllers.

move your `ServerRequestInterface $request` to `__contruct()`